# Dart basic auth not working (dart:io) (UPDATED to working code)

Tags: dart, dart-io

I'm working with the Harvest API, a pretty standard web service API, and my curl requests are working just fine while my Dart HttpClient requests are not. Here is my curl request (with sensitive information disguised, of course):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -u "address@domain.com:password" \
  https://my_domain.harvestapp.com/account/who_am_i
```

**UPDATE** --- The following code now works:

```dart
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.addCredentials(
  Uri.parse('https://my_domain.harvestapp.com/account/who_am_i'),
  'realm',
  new HttpClientBasicCredentials('address@domain.com', 'password')
);
client.getUrl(Uri.parse('https://my_domain.harvestapp.com/account/who_am_i'))
  .then((HttpClientRequest req) {
    req.headers
      ..add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, 'application/json')
      ..add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json');

    return req.close();
  })
  .then((HttpClientResponse res) {
    print(res);
    client.close();
  });
}
```

Obviously I would like to do more than simply `print` the response, but no matter what, the `res` object ends up being `null`, which means that the request is failing in some respect. Does anything seem awry or amiss? I'm at a loss for now.

Comment: Try calling `addCredentials` before calling `getUrl`. Also try `return req.close()`.

Comment: @MarioP That works in the sense that it will return a non-null `res` variable and a message from the server: `You must be authenticated with Harvest to complete this request.` But somehow the authentication itself doesn't seem to be going through.

Comment: Hm. Shouldn't the parameter to `Uri.parse` also match the URL in `getUrl`?

Comment: @MarioP You're right. That was a mistake in copying and pasting. Unfortunately, still doesn't work :/

Comment: @MarioP Actually, in going back and fixing my copy/paste error, I noticed a tiny typo. The above code works just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the changes from the original code snippet:

- Call `HttpClient.addCredentials` before calling `HttpClient.getUrl`
- In the `.then((HttpClientRequest))` part, make sure to `return req.close()`
- Make sure the URLs in `addCredentials` and `getUrl` match.